# Global variable and thread

Tags: c#, .net

My program, should do: In other thread write each result to global array. A main thread read from global array and put on screen.

It't make in Windows Form Aplication. Other question, how show result in textbox step by step. Normaly, all resault is show on the end of a loop. How refresh a Form in everyone move. And how change view in textbox. Normally I see the first number - 1-, I need see last number - 199 - automatically.

I have eception:

> Warning    1   Field 'WFA_watki.Form1.tab' is never assigned to, and
>   will always have its default value null

My code:

```
namespace WFA_watki
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] tab; //----- exception -----

        void licz()
        {
            int wynik = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                wynik =+ i;
                tab[i] = wynik;

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Fnish thread 1. result: " + wynik);


        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Thread watek1 = new Thread(licz);
             watek1.Start();

             Thread.Sleep(1000);

             for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
             {
                 textBox1.Text += tab[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
             }      


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an exception.

Comment: That build warning is pretty clear, and has nothing to do with your attempts at threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tab` is *defined* but never initialised - that means you have said *what* it is, but never set it to anything. You then attempt to access elements in it even though you haven't initialised it.

Try this:

```
int[] tab = new int[100];
```

I've given it a size of 100 because you have a loop iterating up to that value in your `button1_Click` function.

Comment: I would suggest making just "enlightening" hints and not complete answers for the questions which look like beginner's ones. I firmly believe this would bring more benefit to the topicstarter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you seem to get not an exception, but a compiler warning. Nevertheless, the warning is correct: you never assign your `tab` variable. In C# (contrary to some other languages) you have to allocate the array explicitly. Maybe the constructor is a good place for it. Without it, `tab` is just declared to *be able* to contain an `int` array, but it still doesn't *actually* contain the array.

Answer (score 0):

You never declare the array size of tab. The easiest thing to do in this case IMO is to just use a list of type int such that

```
List<int> tab = new List<int>();
```

and you can freely add to the List.

```
tab.Add(wynik);
```

As well as loop through the list

```
tab.Count();
```

The only major consideration for an array otherwise would be due to .Net version(2 or better) or serious performance consideration. 
For more on generics (list of type) see this msdn article.
[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.80).aspx)